# What is the Z-transform of the convolution of a signal with a delayed itself?

Tags: convolution, z-transform

By time-shift and convolution property we can infer that:

$$
y(t)=x(t)*x(t)
$$

$$
y(t-1)=x(t-1)*x(t-1)
$$

$$
Z\{y(t-1)\}=z^{-1}Z\{y(t)\}=z^{-1}Z\{x(t)*x(t)\}=z^{-1}X(z)X(z)
$$

But, if the signal *y* is a convolution of a signal whith a delayed itself,
$$
y(t)=x(t)*x(t-1)
$$
What would be the Z-transform of it in terms of *X(z)*?
$$
Z\{y(t)\}=Z\{x(t)*x(t-1)\}=?
$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the beginning of your post when you substitute the $t - 1$ in $y(t - 1) = x(t - 1) * x(t - 1)$. This is due to the unfortunate abuse of notation regarding the convolution of functions $f * g$ as $f(t) * g(t)$ instead, but your solution is still correct.

Let’s use $\tilde{}$ above a function name for shifting by one in general. Then it turns out that $\widetilde{x * x} = x * \widetilde{x}$, so the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform will *still* be $z^{-1} X(z) \cdot X(z)$ in your second example.

Proof of the identity:

$$\begin{align}
(x * \widetilde{x})(t) &= \sum_k x(k) \cdot \widetilde{x}(t - k) \\
&= \sum_k x(k) \cdot x(t - k - 1) \\
&= \sum_k x(k) \cdot x(\color{red}{t - 1} - k) \\
&= (x * x)(t - 1) \\
&= (\widetilde{x * x})(t). 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation @shoteyes!